# How do I redirect to https on Openshift?

Tags: python, .htaccess, redirect, flask, openshift

I'm trying to redirect to https on Openshift and remove www. I used Openshift's suggested rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This redirects successfully for `domain-name.com` but not for `www.domain-name.com`, which redirects to `https://domain-name.com/wsgi.py`. I'm confused as to why it's redirecting to /wsgi.py and I'm not sure how to correct it.

If it matters, it's a Python Flask app. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have another redirect rule?

Comment: That's the only redirect rule. If it matters, the cname records for domain-name.com and www.domain-name.com both point to app-domain.rhcloud.com

Answer (score 0):

So its most likely redirecting to /wsgi.py because the `OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION` environment variable sets your entry point. You can change the entry point with the `rhc set-env OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION=<preferred entry point>` command.